# Export Functions of DLL's as seen by depends

Tags: dll, dllexport, depends

I was looking over the list of  functions that were exported from a dll using depends and i noticed some weird symbols included with the names. They are of the format

`??0Function Name@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z`

Also 0 maybe replaced by some other number.

The number of @@ and the alphabets  vary.

Can anybody tell what they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the name of a C++ identifier that was decorated by the C++ compiler.  You can run the undname.exe utility from the Visual Studio Command Prompt to convert it back to the original C++ declaration:

```
C:\>undname ??0Foo@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "??0Foo@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z"
is :- "public: __cdecl Foo::Foo(class Foo const & __ptr64) __ptr64"
```

Which makes it the copy constructor for the Foo class, compiled to 64-bit code.  The exact decoration algorithm is not documented that I know of.  In general, name decoration is used to avoid linker symbol collisions, necessary because C++ supports overloading.  You can suppress decoration by using `extern "C"` but that can't work on a C++ class.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations you might be interested to undecorate these names programatically using an API Microsoft is providing [UnDecorateSymbolName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).